# Transition elements that are moved by your transitions?

Tags: vue.js

The transitions in Vue are really nice, but the problem is, when the DOM re-adjusts after something has faded out, it's jarring. So, the thing with the transition fades in and out, but then all the surrounding elements clunk into the resultant space.

How do people deal with this?

Comment: I think you perhaps need to improve CSS and maybe html, please show your HTML markup and transition CSS first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what effect you are trying to achieve. If you want to fade out then slide the other page elements in to place you will probably want to use javascript animations instead of the standard fade transition. This effect is quite straight forward using something like jQuery or [velocity](http://velocityjs.org). All you need to do is create two methods in your view model and bind them using `v-on:enter` and `v-on:leave`, so in your HTML you have:

```
  <transition v-on:enter="slideFadeIn" v-on:leave="fadeSlideOut">
    <div v-show="show">
       // Fadeable content
    </div>
  </transition>
```

Then you just need to create those two methods (`slideFadeIn` and  `fadeSlideOut`) which fade out the element then slide it up, like so (I'm using velocity here):

```
 methods: {
   slideFadeIn(el, done) {
      $(el).velocity('slideDown', 200).velocity({
        opacity: 1
      }, {
        complete: done
      });
    },
    fadeSlideOut(el, done) {
        $(el).velocity({
          opacity: 0,
        },  { duration: 1500 }).velocity('slideUp', 200, {
          complete: done
        });
      }
  },
```

Then make sure you have a flag in `data` that you can toggle to show and hide the element:

```
data: {
  show: true
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle for the entire thing: https://jsfiddle.net/9dt4z4c6/

Of course, you can tweak this to do pretty much any type of animation you want, here's a fiddle that fades and slides at the same time:

https://jsfiddle.net/rd9mqs6n/

Although, if you like that effect, you can also do it using a normal transition, which is a bit neater:

https://jsfiddle.net/43zL2cw3/

Comment: Thanks for this - with your code I'm finally getting somewhere. I'll have to think about whether its worth including velocity for this (what would be the equivalent to the above in jQuery? which I already have in the project)

Comment: Velocity was pretty much designed to allow you to swap it with `jQuery`, so the `jQuery` code is similar, here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1eg7pg5c/

Comment: Gah! doesn't work with jQuery lite. Makes me feel really indulgent bringing in extra framework bulk just for this. On the other hand, it's a really nice effect....thanks again.